# What is php-fpm writing to disk (php-fpm disk i/o)?

Tags: php, nginx, io, opcache, fpm

I'm wondering why is php-fpm using disk for writing, my application doesn't interact with disk at all, I do not have any errors in the log.

I have the following info:

```
  PID USERNAME     VCSW  IVCSW   READ  WRITE  FAULT  TOTAL PERCENT COMMAND
91470 www          2304     55      0     11      0     11   2.23% php-fpm
91528 www          2043     78      0     22      0     22   4.46% php-fpm
91331 www          1866     80      0     35      0     35   7.10% php-fpm
91534 www          1482     53      0     56      0     56  11.36% php-fpm
91602 www          2116     84      0      9      0      9   1.83% php-fpm
91468 www          1860    100      0     23      0     23   4.67% php-fpm
91410 www          1031     63      0     20      0     20   4.06% php-fpm
91601 www          1288     65      0     32      0     32   6.49% php-fpm
91592 www          1466     15      0     31      0     31   6.29% php-fpm
91535 www          1354     72      0      3      0      3   0.61% php-fpm
91471 www          1374     61      0     27      0     27   5.48% php-fpm
91404 www          1037     61      2      8      0     10   2.03% php-fpm
```

When I do "fstat | grep php" I can see it has many pipes open, few internet streams and local streams.

The same application with hiphop-php has 0 reads and 0 writes.

Please advice, may be it is related to some configuration option I'm missing. I'm using opcache, so disk i/o should not happen at all. How can I debug it?

I use SSDs, so I do not want any disk i/o to happen at all when I run php-fpm.

**EDIT** 
It seems that when I post data to php-fpm it is being piped to the disk, the data is not big, it is under 100KB. How can this be avoided, so it uses the memory instead of writing to the disk?

Thanks!

Comment: some logging perhaps ?

Comment: very few, only when the php-fpm child processes are rotated, it shouldn't cause this much of writes.

Comment: It writes a lot of things for sure, session information, looks for config files, etc. Also in Linux everything is in the file system, this information can be saved in memory or in disk.

Comment: I do not use any sessions in the app. session auto start is off. It is the same behavior even if I run <?php exit; ?> application

Comment: I share your concern about excessive writes on SSDs. My apache/fpm processes are dead silent IOPS write (restful, stateless API). I know this may be obvious, but did you nuke xdebug (or equivalent) ?  that is a killer , perf wise and IO wise.

Comment: It is piping something, can this be some buffering between nginx and php-fpm? PHP output buffering is also off.

Comment: Are POST requests to php-fpm being piped?

Comment: fpm listens on port (not same boxes as access apache)

Comment: It seems that when I post data to php-fpm it is being piped to the disk, the data is not big, it is under 100KB. How can this be avoided, so it uses the memory instead of writing to the disk?

Comment: if you can do it with nginx, try to have fpm listen on 127.0.0.1:NNNN (port of your choice, typically 9000) and configure nginx to connect fpm on localhost:NNNN. This is how i do it in my vhosts:`ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*do\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:8001/usr/local/var/www/htdocs/PortableEHR.backend/api/do.php`, where my NNNN is 8001 (this is my dev box)

Comment: You could avoid PHP to handle the upload all together and use the upload module of nginx. See this article for a detailed implementation https://jiripudil.cz/blog/blazing-fast-file-upload-through-nginx